# internal server error and forbidden access

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, httprequest, lxml

I am try to do web scraping of a website with the following code.

```
import http.client
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from lxml.html import fromstring
from http.client import HTTPConnection #as _HTTPConnection, HTTPException

base_url = "https://apct.gov.in/apportal/Search/ViewAPVATDealers.aspx"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
path = fromstring(soup.decode('utf-8'))

header = {
          "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
          "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
          "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
          "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36",
          }

url = "https://apct.gov.in/apportal/Search/ViewAPVATDealers.aspx"
form_data={}
form_data["__EVENTTARGET"] = ""
form_data["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""
form_data["__LASTFOCUS"] = ""
form_data["__VIEWSTATE"] = path.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value')
form_data["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = path.xpath('//*[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]/@value')
form_data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dropact"] = "LT"
form_data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Ddl_Divisions"] = "GUNTUR"
form_data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Ddl_Circles"] = "All Circles"
form_data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlbusines"] = "Agent"
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('apct.gov.in')
url_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(header)
          # 1 # 
# conn.request("POST", url, url_params, header)
# response = conn.getresponse()
# print(response.status, response.reason)
# data = response.read()
# print(data)
# conn.close()
         # 2 #
# r = requests.post(url,form_data,url_params)
# #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
# print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

When i run the 1st comment part to retrieve response it shows `403 forbidden` and when i run the 2nd commented part it shows `internal server error`.
Can anyone find any mistake in any line due to which i am getting this error. I know with such limited information it is difficult to identify the error, but this was my last option.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `403` means server refuses your request as you are not _authenticated_. _Internal Server Error_ happens when server encounters an error(usually an Exception) and returns http status code `500`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i know these things still i am not able to spot my mistake here..

Comment: These are not your (_direct_) mistakes. Note the term _server_ in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got to know that there was no mistake in my code, rather the website shows some error if filled with those particular values.